# How to work with night vision camera input (Frames) in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm developing an app which uses Night Vision camera to recognize the face features even under low light conditions. My app is made to work at night, I've no problems working with camera in day light, to make it work in low light I want to use night vision camera (Please suggest me any good night vision camera for Processing using OpenCV). Or is there any way to get better quality image under low light even from the normal camera.

Answer (score 1):

Most digital cameras are able to see infrared light. You can easily verify this by pointing a tv remote at a camera while pressing buttons. 
Shining ir leds to illuminate the scene is pretty common in surveillance just look at this camera http://thespystore.com/image/cache/data/weatherproof-night-vision-camera-bulir11-500x500.JPG. Usually you can't use color for night vision. It's the same as having a grayscale image. Good luck

Comment: Can I use normal Night Vision camera for my app so that OpenCV can process the frames and gives the result.

Comment: what OS do you use? in Windows, OpenCV can basically access all DirectShow compatible devices directly.

Comment: I use both Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7. What about Ubuntu does it support.

Comment: @Micka How can I achieve this, any possible solutions.

Comment: @PUNITH can you access it with GraphStudio DirectShow?